# Why does UserDetailsService return null in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

A simple spring boot app has a custom UserDetailsService.  The Spring Boot Controller is called by an AngularJS app, and authentication requests from the AngularJS app are made to the backend at the `/user` url pattern.  But login requests are causing the controller logs to indicate that the controller is not finding the `/user` url pattern, and that the UserDetailsService is thus returning null.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order to enable client requests for the backend `/user` url pattern to find the controller method and thus also correctly instantiate the custom `UserDetailsService`?**

The app is so simple that the controller is less than 200 lines of code.

The code for the controller is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "demo", considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class UiApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // Match everything without a suffix (so not a static resource)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }


    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Users users;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(users);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/message", "/home")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }

    @Service
    class Users implements UserDetailsService {

        private UserRepository repo;

        @Autowired
        public Users(UserRepository repo) {
            this.repo = repo;
        }

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = repo.findByName(username);
            if (user == null) {
                return null;
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils
                    .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
            if (username.equals("admin")) {
                auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN");
            }
            String password = user.getPassword();
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, auth);
        }

    }

    @Repository
    interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
        User findByName(String name);
    }

    @Entity
    class User {
        @GeneratedValue
        @Id
        private Long iduser;
        private String name;
        private String password;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
        private Collection<SessionLog> sessionLogCollection;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

    @Entity
    class SessionLog {

        @GeneratedValue
        @Id
        private Long id;
        private String sessionid;
        @ManyToOne(optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "iduser")
        private User user;

        public String getSessionid() {
            return sessionid;
        }
    }

}
```

And the complete stack trace produced by the login request is:

```
2015-12-30 14:27:07.628 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /js/navigation/login.html has an empty filter list
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/css/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/js/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/images/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/error'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/configprops'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/configprops/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/configprops.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/configprops/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/autoconfig'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/autoconfig/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/autoconfig.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/autoconfig/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/metrics'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/metrics/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/metrics.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/metrics/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.617 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/env'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/env/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/env.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/env/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/trace'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/trace/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/trace.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/trace/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/health']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/health'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/health/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.620 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/health/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/beans'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/beans/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/beans.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/beans/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/info']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/info'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/info/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/info/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/dump'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/dump/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/dump.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/dump/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/mappings'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings/**']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/mappings/**'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings.*']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/mappings.*'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings/']
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/user'; against '/mappings/'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.621 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@71f7b6fe. A new one will be created.
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@a3b708e
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: ''
2015-12-30 14:27:21.622 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.630 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /user' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2015-12-30 14:27:21.630 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /user at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.632 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'admin'
2015-12-30 14:27:21.632 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2015-12-30 14:27:22.155 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
2015-12-30 14:27:22.155 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation
2015-12-30 14:27:22.155 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2015-12-30 14:27:22.155 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint@784c2ce0
2015-12-30 14:27:22.155 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-12-30 14:27:22.155 DEBUG 4398 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The controller method is found. The problem is this code:

```
if (user == null) {
    return null;
}
```

As you clearly can see in the log messages:

```
Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation
```

Returning null is not allowed in a UserDetailsService implementation.

So check if you have an entry in your database for the admin user and remove the `return null` and throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` instead.

Comment: Given the number of downvotes and the 3 votes to close the other posting, I deleted it. I think the problem was that I had a redundant `User` entity outside the controller that I posted, in addition to an outside `Role` entity, which explained those redundant tables in the generated dbase schema. Copying the project, stripping everything extraneous in the app and deleting the database, then launching the stripped copy resulted in the app authenticating properly. Thank you for your help. I will pay it forward by helping someone else in another aspect of life that comes easier for me.